# Conforming to UITextField Delegate Using Subclass Textfield

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, uitextfield

I have a subclass, CustomCell, which inherits from my parent class, CreateEvent. The subclass describes the individual cells for the table view cell, which is on the CreateEvent View controller. In one specific cell, I have a textfield, that is linked to the CustomCell file, but I am having trouble getting the value from that textfield when a user enters into the textfield. I am also having trouble dismissing the keyboard with outside touches and pressing the return key, but I am primarily focused on getting the text from the textfield. I am familiar with doing these functionalities on ONE normal swift file but because this is a subclass and two swift files, I'm not sure what to do. This is my code:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var entranceFeeTextField: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib() {
     super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
     super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

and

```
class CreateEventVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    // the following code describes the array for an expandable drop down 
    if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellNormal" {
        if let primaryTitle = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = primaryTitle as? String
        }

        eventType = ((cellDescriptors[0] as! NSMutableArray)[0] as! NSDictionary)["primaryTitle"]! as! String
        if let secondaryTitle = currentCellDescriptor["secondaryTitle"] {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = secondaryTitle as? String
        }
    }
    else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellTextfield" {
        cell.textField.placeholder = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
    }


    else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellValuePicker" {
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
    }

    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}


func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField:UITextField) -> Bool {
    entranceFeeAmount = cell.entranceFeeTextField.text!

    return true;
}

}
```

My main question is whether I am conforming to the UITextField Delegates properly, because I am not able to print out the value of the entranceFeeTextField.

Comment: Where is the text field's `delegate` set?

Comment: I tried putting cell.entranceFeeTextField.delegate = self into the tableview but it would not compile. Is that what you mean?